# installing qt-x11 on macports failed

Tags: macos, macports, qt4

I'm trying to install qt4-x11 on OSX Lion 10.7.5. 'port install qt4-x11' failed and I checked the log it says:

```
:info:configure Creating qmake. Please wait...
:info:configure /usr/bin/clang++ -c -o project.o -pipe -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -I/opt/local/var/macport$
:info:configure In file included from project.cpp:38:
:info:configure In file included from ./project.h:41:
:info:configure In file included from /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-ope$
:info:configure In file included from /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-ope$
:info:configure In file included from /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-ope$
:info:configure In file included from /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-ope$
:info:configure In file included from /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-ope$
:info:configure /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.4.3/incl$
:info:configure #    error "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
:info:configure      ^
:info:configure 1 error generated.
:info:configure make: *** [project.o] Error 1
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_qt4-x11/qt4-x11/work/qt-x11-open$
:info:configure Exit code: 2
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port qt4-x11 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
```

Does it mean I can't do it on Lion?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that way, however, when I looked at the [QT-project](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html) page for supported platforms, it specifically mentions Lion as supported.  It does [require](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-mac.html) Xcode to be installed.  It would appear that the MacPorts collection is a version behind, as QT5.0 is available on their [download](http://qt-project.org/downloads) page.

**In summary, it appears you cannot install QT on your system with MacPorts at this time, but it is available for Mac OS X Lion installation from the QT's project site.**